# Html invalid validation

Tags: html, html-lists

so I'm fairly new to HTML, and I'm making myself a simple site with html 5 and I was validation to check for errors and I got this:

Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)`<div class="home"><a href="sitename/"><li>Home</a></li></div>`

and here's the code:

```
<ul>
    <div class="home"><a href="sitename/"><li>Home</a></li></div>
    <div class="About"><a href="#"><li>About</a></li></div>
    <div class="Contact"><a href="#"><li>Contact</a></li></div>
    <div class="empty"><a href="#"><li>   </a></li></div>
</ul>
```

What do I have to do to fix the errors?

Comment: Wouldn't putting the 'div's inside the 'li's be more logical? And nesting the tags properly?

Answer (score 4):

its clear

1.Line 15, Column 22: Element div not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

```
    <div class="home"><a href="http://rexnoz.zxq.net/"><li>Home</a></li></div>
```

2.Error Line 15, Column 67: End tag a violates nesting rules.

```
    <div class="home"><a href="http://rexnoz.zxq.net/"><li>Home</a></li></div>
```

3.Error Line 15, Column 67: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.

```
     <div class="home"><a href="http://rexnoz.zxq.net/"><li>Home</a></li></div>
```

what 2,3 point is that you started `div` inside the `li` and closed the `li` fist should be `div`

[from w3c](http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http://rexnoz.zxq.net/)

Answer (score -1):

Should be

`<div><li><a>Home</a></li></div>`